# Variables in awk code for minimun and maximun

Tags: awk

The purpose is to get the minimum and maximum from from characters 7-12 in the first line of output file.

I got the output desired using 2 variables (min-max) to include in the AWK code.

**I believe this can be done in easy method, avoiding the variables..**

**file**

```
12 285000008
12 285000005
12 285000011
12 285000013
12 285000019
12 285000027
12 285000032
14 285235942
14 285235940
```

**My code**

```
ft=`sort -k1.7,1.12bn file | head -1 | cut -c 7-12`
lt=`sort -k1.7,1.12bn file | tail -1 | cut -c 7-12`

awk -v fv="$ft" -v lv="$lt" 'BEGIN{
           printf("%s,%s",fv,lv ORS)        
}
{
if($1>12) print "YES", $0 
}' file
```

**output desired.**

```
000005,235942
YES 14 285235942
YES 14 285235940
```

Thanks ind advance

Comment: Not clear, please do let me know how are you getting min and max variables to use in `awk` code, try to add more information for expected output how you are getting it and let us know then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    cur = substr($0,7)
    min = ( (NR>1) && (min < cur) ? min : cur )
    max = ( (NR>1) && (max > cur) ? max : cur )
}
$1 > 12 {
    yess[++numYess] = $0
}
END {
    print min "," max
    for (yesNr=1; yesNr<=numYess; yesNr++) {
        print "YES", yess[yesNr]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
000005,235942
YES 14 285235942
YES 14 285235940
```

or if you don't mind a 2 pass approach with a sort and a pipe:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    cur = substr($0,7)
    min = (NR==1 ? cur : min)
    max = cur
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    print min "," max
}
$1 > 12 {
    print "YES", $0
}

$ sort -k1.7n file | awk -f tst.awk - file
000005,235942
YES 14 285235942
YES 14 285235940
```

Comment: Ed, as usual your codes are awesome.. Many thanks for the help and sharing your skills.. Appreciate that

Answer (score 1):

This solution is completely based by seeing your attempt and your desired output only, in case you have more conditions you should let us know on same then, try following which will NOT create any BASH variables it deals with direct `awk` variables in single code.

```
awk -v min=$(sort -k1.7,1.12bn Input_file | head -1 | cut -c 7-12) -v max=$(sort -k1.7,1.12bn Input_file  | tail -1 | cut -c 7-12)  '
BEGIN{
  print min,max
}
$1>12{
  print "YES",$0
}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
000005 235942
YES 14 285235942
YES 14 285235940
```

Comment: RavinderSingh, yes  the purpose was to don't create any BASH variables and deals with direct awk variables in single code.

Comment: That's reading the input file 3 times and using 3 commands plus pipes for 2 of the 3 passes. Seems like overkill to me for such a simple task.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you Ed sir I thought that but since OP needed answer in this way so given answer within awk variables.